# Rights of Joint administrators of a property

Tags: property, india, ownership, indian-constitutional-law, succession

If legal heirs of a joint property have acquired the letter of administration of the joint property, can a single co-owner sell his share (in india)?

Edited to add:

Can the said co-owner go for a partition deed?

Comment: Probably a bit late now, but what state is the property in and what faith(s) are the heirs?

Comment: Relevant https://www.vidhikarya.com/legal-blog/laws-for-partition-of-property-in-india

Answer (score 1):

Can the said co-owner go for a partition deed?

**YES**

But it will have to be agreed by all the joint-owners.

The actual process on how to go about it will depend on what the property is (e.g. agricultural land, dwelling, or is movable / immovable), the owners' religion(s) and what state the property is located in. [This article](https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/housing.com/news/partition-deed/amp/) gives some more detail - especially around Hindu law.

Answer (score 0):

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

### No

Ownership of property as “joint tenants” means the property is owned as a single indivisible unit.

Conversely, “tenants-in-common” own their shares separately and can sell them individually.

Comment: Can the said co-owner go for a partition deed?